# Wordpress: enqueue script adds rubbish to script source

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firebug

When adding script to theme Wordpress add this text to the beginning of the script source:

```
<div style="display:none"><b></b>
</div>
```

and script breaks, and Firebug says:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Whats the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: There's absolutely no javascript in the question. Except wait, are you trying to say that you've put HTML inside the JS file or something?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the semi-colon - ; in that code. That is what that Syntax error means. Also Bold is not `<b></b>` ...it is Strong- `<strong></strong>` . That was deprecated a few years ago.

Correct code would be:

`<div style="display:none;"><strong></strong></div>`